# How to plot in R like this?

Tags: r, plot, parallel-coordinates

How to plot in R like this(same as the graphs) ? Could you please post the R code in your answer?

I am a R beginner and I find it is difficult to plot in R for me.

[image]
[image]

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you don't post an explanation of the kind of data you have (preferably using `dput` to show a reproducible version of the data itself) this won't really be possible to answer.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: not so. First, the data is clearly the builtin iris dataset. Second, the OP is only looking for the general name and function call. Not to exactly reproduce. This question is good and on-topic, and the downvoting is misguided.

Comment: @smci well, this is a blast from the past (4+ years ago). Incidentally, I didn't downvote

Comment: David I didn't say you did, but what you wrote is incorrect and likely encouraged the 6 people who did. `ggparcoord/ggpcp` is very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom graph is called a "parallel coordinates plot". You can do a quick Google search to find several ways of doing this in R. Here are two, both using the "iris" dataset.

1. ggplot2

   With this approach, you basically say which columns have the data you want to plot, and specify your grouping variable using `geom_line()`.

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   p <- ggpcp(iris, vars = names(iris[1:4]))
   p + geom_line(aes(color = Species))
   ```

   [image]
2. MASS

   The approach here is similar. First specify your data, then specify how your data are grouped (in the case of the "iris" dataset, there are three species, with 50 observations each).

   ```
   library(MASS)
   parcoord(iris[-5], col = rep(1:3, each = 50))
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Could you please delete the answer so that I can delete the question? I'm sorry for that. I have been downvote for more than 5 times and I'm banned to ask question. Thanks for your help : )